# Inbound TCP/IP connection failed: 'function' object has no attribute 'peer_subscribe'

Tags: ros, python, ros-kinetic, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two nodes, one publishes a topic (https://github.com/pitosalas/easy_filter/blob/master/scripts/obstacle_detector.py) that the other one (https://github.com/pitosalas/easy_filter/blob/master/scripts/livelyobstacles.py) subscribes to. What happens is if I run the publsher by itself, all is well. But if I do a rostopic echo on the relevant topic then the publisher starts throwing that exception.

Three notes:

1. I've been debugging for a while, with control-c and kill commands to try and cleanup. I could be in some kind of bad state. But then my question is: how do I tell and how do I get out of the bad state? What do I reboot, my development computer, my robot, my roscore computer, all of them? And how do I avoid getting into this state.
2. Minor: is the / before the topic name (when used in the publish or subscribe call) required, optional or sometimes yes and sometimes no?
3. I am working in python,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299339/inbound-tcp/ip-connection-failed:-%27function%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27peer_subscribe%27/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-08-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2018-08-01**:
It's much more likely that someone can help you debug your code if you show the code.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-08-01**:
Done. See links added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, I found the bug. See line 11 and 12 of the obstacle_detector.py:

```
    self.sub = rospy.Subscriber('/scan', LaserScan, self.scan, queue_size=1)
    self.pub = rospy.Publisher('obstacle', Obstacle, self.scan, queue_size =10)
```

As they say... "never mind" :(

---

Originally posted by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) with karma: 628 on 2018-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sirrarthur](https://answers.ros.org/users/76384/sirrarthur/) on 2021-06-29**:
I made the same mistake putting the wrong arguments into the publisher. In my case I just wrote "10" instead of  "queue_size = 10"